# Edit XLSX styles in optimized writing with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I know that is not possible define styles in optimized writing, but is there any way to write the header defining styles, and then turn optimized write to true to write the rest of the data?
Something like this?:

```
wb = Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
ws = wb.create_sheet()
#change styles and write header
wb.optimized_write=True
#write rest of data
```

Comment: Is header the first line of your sheet?

Comment: yes, indeed.It's the first line, and it is the first written in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, not directly.

Longer answer, is you would have to update `openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet.ExcelDumpWriter` and `openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet.DumpWorksheet`.

Have a look at how `DumpWorksheet` writes the rows using `DumpWorksheet.append()`, with one of two pre-set styles in (it sets the style for a datetime cell).

```
# Example on how you would use this
from openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet import ExcelDumpWriter, DumpWorksheet
from openpyxl.writer.styles import StyleWriter

wb.optimized_worksheet_class=MyDumpWorksheet

my_header_style = Style()
my_header_style.font.bold = True

writer = ExcelDumpWriter(workbook)
writer.style_writer._style_list.append(my_header_style)
writer.save(filename)

# A start on how you would overload DumpWorksheet.append()
class MyDumpWorksheet(DumpWorksheet):
    def __init__(self, parent_workbook, title):
        DumpWorksheet.__init__(self, parent_workbook, title)

    def append(self, row):
        """Overload to write the correct styles"""

        # .... keep the initial setup before this
        attrs = {'r': '%d' % row_idx,
                 'spans': '1:%d' % span}
        start_tag(doc, 'row', attrs)

        if row == 1:
            # Assuming cell is a string here --
            for col_idx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell is None:
                    continue

                coordinate = '%s%d' % (get_column_letter(col_idx + 1), row_idx)
                attributes = {'r': coordinate}

               # Assuming string!!
                cell = self._string_builder.add(cell)

                # 2 here refers to the style you added to writer.style_writer._style_list.
                attributes['t'] = {'type':Cell.TYPE_STRING, 'style':'2'} 
                start_tag(doc, 'c', attributes)
                tag(doc, 'v', body='%s' % cell)
                end_tag(doc, 'c')
            end_tag(doc, 'row')
        else:
            # Keep to the original append() logic
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to use styles in write-only mode. To do this you use a `WriteOnlyCell` and include it or them in any iterable you pass into `append()` to the Worksheet.